# Pass xml response from one sampler to another in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

How to extract values from the below xml response and pass on to the next request in JMeter?

Sample response:

```
<Arrayoftoken>
<Id></ID>
<emp>
 <Id> </Id>
 <Name></Name>
 <dept>
   <Id> </Id>
   <Location></Location>
 </dept> 
</emp>
</ArrayofToken>
```

I need to extract token Id {the very first Id} and the dept id, {Id inside dept}.

Tried with xpath extractor. But its not able to return 2 values. please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 regular expression extractors on the request on which you expect the above mentioned response.

In first regular expression extractor:
your ***Regular Expression*** should be

```
<Arrayoftoken>.*\n.(.+?)<
```

In second regular expression extractor:
your ***Regular Expression*** should be

```
<dept>.*\n.*<Id>(.+?)<
```

Hope this will help.